# Need to return multiple rows of SQL data in C#

Tags: c#, sql

For a school project I need to create a Windows Forms App that has a database connected to it. I'm making an app that displays movies, along with their actors and characters and such. I have a listbox that lists all movies, when you click on a movie information about it appears in an other listbox, and the characters with their actors appear in an other listbox. I won't get the last part to work because I don't know how to make a query of that.
These are the tables I have for that query:

```
Movie:             Actor:                  Character:

MovieID  Title     ActorID  Name        ActorID  MovieID  Name
1        movie1    1        john           1     1        shawn
2        movie2    2        will           1     2        barry
3        movie3    3        bill           2     3        drake
4        movie4    4        gill           3     4        nate
                                           4     3        kelly
```

I've came as far as this query:

```
"SELECT Character.Name, Actor.Name 
FROM Character 
INNER JOIN Actor ON Actor.ActorID = Character.ActorID
INNER JOIN Movie ON Movie.MovieID =" + MovieID;
```

the second MovieID in the query being the MovieID that is selected in the listbox. Does anyone know how I can extract that MovieID from the listbox or is there an easier method?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2 
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.column1 = table2.column1;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

You can use DisplayMember and ValueMember

[ListControl.DisplayMember Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Character.Name as charactername, Actor.Name as actorname, movie.title as movietitle
FROM Character 
INNER JOIN Actor ON Actor.ActorID = Character.ActorID
INNER JOIN Movie ON Movie.MovieID = character.MovieID
```

You can add a where to filter the movie

```
WHERE movie.movieid = yourvariable
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query !

```
SELECT 
      c.Name  AS 'Character Name'  , 
      a.Name  AS 'Actor Name'
FROM 
      Movie m                      ,
      Character c                  ,
      Actor a
WHERE 
      m.MovieID = c.MovieID
AND
      a.ActorID = c.ActorID
AND
      m.MovieID = '" + variable_name_of_your_movie_ID_in_C# + "'
```